# DVD Rom is not detected under Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, dvd, device-manager

I know this issue is reported several times on this forum and over the internet but all those posts mark an answers which is not suitable for my case:

The issue:

DVD ROM Is visible in BIOS
In is not visible in Device Manager 
It is not shown in "This Computer" listing all available drives
It is not show in Disk management
DVD is visible in Intel Rapid enterprise manger as ATAPI device

What I have tries so far:

1. Check UpperFilter, LowerFilter, UpperFilter.bak and LowerFilter.bak in the Windows Registry in the following location:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4d36e965-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}

They are not present there so the solution that is based on deleting these values does not work in my case

2. Created `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\atapi\Controller0` key and `EnumDevice1` with DWORD value = `1` and reboot. Continue with this procedure upto EnumDevice5 = 5
3. Checked if a DVD ROM was visible in hidden devices in Device Manager.
   It was! Then I applied the solution I found in one of the forums, which suggested to uninstall hidden devices (my DVD) then uninstall SATA AHCI standard controller and reboot.

I did it and then after reboot the Standard controller is back again but no more hidden DVD ROM .

4. Next suggestion I found was to modify the `CSConfigFlag` under `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SCSI` registry key to value 1 and then 2, each time rebooting, but in my case I do not have such key.

The only `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum` key that is under the ENum is PCI and no SCSI

5. I tried to use the DVD Repair Tool version 0.4.3.430 by Rizonesoft as many people reported in helped them, in my case it does nothing.
6. Scan whole computer with paid antivirus software - nothing found
7. Used `sfc /scannnow` - to check windows installation - no major issues were found
8. Run troubleshooting from control panel and went through Hardware and Devices troubleshooter.

My configuration is as follows:

```
Asus P79X WS Mobo + Intel i7-4930K
There are 2HDD in RAID 1 and 2SSD without RAID
RAID is created using RSTe Controller (RAID is selected in BIOS)
2 SSD are connected to SATA6G ports
2 HDD are connected to port 3 and 4 SATA3G
DVD ROM is connected to port 5
Mobo has a total of 6 ports.
DVD is Samsung SH-224DB (TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-224DB)
```

The problem started after CPU Upgrade from Intel i7 3820.
Before DVD ROM was working, with exactly the same BIOS configuration (including RAID setting)

I can boot from the DVD, I can boot from USD and access the DVD so It seems the hardware is working OK. I think it is Windows issue.

The links pointing to the listed solutions are:

1. http://www.askvg.com/optical-drives-are-not-showing-in-my-computer/ (but actually I found it in more than 20 places)
2. http://www.askvg.com/optical-drives-are-not-showing-in-my-computer/ (but actually I found it in more than 20 places)
3. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-dvd-drive-missing/f246ef3d-ff9a-4cd2-9746-7de01184c258
4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekRArk7myeY
5. https://rizonesoft.com/download/dvd-drive-repair/

Do you have any suggestions what could I try else to fix my DVD under Windows (except windows reinstall I hope)?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: What could I do next in order to be able to use DVD ROM again under windows

Comment: I manage to use a restore point (the only I had :( ) so I I was able to restore hidden device in DM. One thing I can add is that after CPU upgrade I had to reinstall Intel Chipset drivers as I was seeing lots of exclamation marks in DM.

Comment: Very interesting discussion here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/dvd-is-not-detected-by-windows-10/514e2faf-3078-443d-9820-1af39d9c3ab6 but so far no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was checking every possible solutions.
The description of all of them is under this link (Microsoft Forum) http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/dvd-is-not-detected-by-windows-10/514e2faf-3078-443d-9820-1af39d9c3ab6 
None of them work.
Finally I bought a cheap $20 PCI Express 2xSATA controller and my DVD is working again. The link also described the reason of this Windows bug.